# Error: navBarController.back() is deprecated, please use $ionicHistory.goBack() instead

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm getting this error

> navBarController.back() is deprecated, please use $ionicHistory.goBack() instead

Although I haven't included any such thing in my controller.

My html has this:

```
<ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-back-button>
```

And

```
$ionicNavBarDelegate.back()// in controller
```

Which might be the cause.

> Note: I'm using ionic 1 and

Comment: show the controller

Comment: which version of ionic?

Comment: I have specified in my question

Answer (score 1):

Use **$ionicHistory.goBack();**

In html:

```
<ion-nav-back-button ng-click="vm.goBack()">
</ion-nav-back-button>
```

In controller:

```
vm.goBack = function() {
     $ionicHistory.goBack();
}
```

This should do it.